# Try to call restful api from python - 'resp' is undefined

Tags: python

I'm new to python.  I am trying to execute the code below from visual studio 2019.  I get an error: name 'resp' is undefined.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import httplib2
# These aren't needed, just for this example
from pprint import pformat
def post_elexon(url):
    http_obj = httplib2.Http()
    resp, content = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='GET',
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'},
)
print ("===Response===")
print (pformat(resp))

print ("===Content===")
print (pformat(content))
print ("===Finished===")
def main():
    post_elexon(
url='https://api.bmreports.com/BMRS/B1770/v1?APIKey=MY_API_KEY&SettlementDate=2015-03-01&Period=1&ServiceType=csv',
)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help would be greaty appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to print `resp()` before `main()` even runs, and even if it did run first, `resp` only exists inside the scope of `post_elexon`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly return `resp` and `content`, as well as only try to print them after `post_elexon` has run:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import httplib2
# These aren't needed, just for this example
from pprint import pformat
def post_elexon(url):
    http_obj = httplib2.Http()
    resp, content = http_obj.request(
        uri=url,
        method='GET',
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=UTF-8'},)
    return resp, content

def main():
    resp, content = post_elexon(url='https://api.bmreports.com/BMRS/B1770/v1?APIKey=MY_API_KEY&SettlementDate=2015-03-01&Period=1&ServiceType=csv',)
    print ("===Response===")
    print (pformat(resp))

    print ("===Content===")
    print (pformat(content))
    print ("===Finished===")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks very much Random Davis!!